# Redirecting all child pages from subdomain

Tags: redirects, wordpress, subdomain

I can't get this redirect working... Can someone point me in the right direction please?

On a WordPress site I want to prevent access to all pages that sit beneath a given parent page. All I want people to see is that parent page.

So if `example.com/subdomain/parent-page` is made up of:

```
parent-page
parent-page/sub-page-1
parent-page/sub-page-2 
...and so on
```

I want all matching sub-pages redirecting to `example.com/subdomain/parent-page`.

My *.htaccess* file sits in the root folder of `example.com/subdomain`.

I think I need `RedirectMatch` for this so I can use regex.

But all my variations of:

```
RedirectMatch 301 parent-page/?* example.com/subdomain/parent-page
```

Do not work for one reason or another. The best result I've had is redirecting pages to the parent domain's "page not found" page!

Clearly I'm missing something here?

Comment: Is `/subdomain` actually part of the (visible) URL?

Answer (score 3):

> On a WordPress site

WordPress uses mod_rewrite to handle the URL routing (pretty URLs) - which I assume you are using - so you should avoid using a mod_alias redirect (`Redirect`, `RedirectMatch`, etc.) in this instance. (Different modules run at different times, regardless of the order of the directives in the .htaccess file, so you can get unexpected results/conflicts. mod_rewrite *usually* runs before mod_alias.)

In .htaccess it's easy enough to redirect `example.com/subdomain/parent-page/<anything>`, but if you only want to redirect existing WordPress pages and 404 when that page does not exist then that is more complex and you should probably seek a WP solution, rather than .htaccess.

Try something like the following at the top of your `example.com/subdomain/.htaccess` file. These directives must come *before* any existing WordPress routing directives.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^parent-page/. /subdomain/parent-page [R=302,L]
```

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. (301's are cached by the browser so can make testing problematic.)

Any URL that starts `/subdomain/parent-page/<something>` will be redirected (regardless of whether that sub-page exists or not). This also helps to avoid a redirect loop.

`RewriteEngine` only needs to appear once in the .htaccess file - preferably (more logical) at the top.

---

> `RedirectMatch 301 parent-page/?* example.com/subdomain/parent-page`

Aside... There are a few things wrong here. The regex is not strictly valid. `*` matches the preceding char 0 or more times (the preceding char is `?`, which is itself a meta character). If you are specifying the domain in the target URL then it must be absolute with protocol etc.